# Visual Studio Web Load Testing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, integration-testing, load-testing, performance-testing

I'm using the Visual Studio load testing to test a web service with a max user load of 2.
So I'm using this would mean the service would get called twice.
However when I look in IIS logs for the Service, I only see a single request each time.
Is this correct?

Comment: To simulate multiple user requests should I be using number of iterations instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A load test simulates multiple users accessing your application concurrently or not.

To run concurrent tests, you should use an appropriate load Pattern : it specifies how the simulated user load is adjusted during a load test. By default, it can be constant-based, step-based, or goal-based. Read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997551.aspx).

To run N tests (concurrently or not), you should use tests Iterations : it specifies the number of iterations to run on all the Web performance and unit tests in all the scenarios in a load test. Read this [How-to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff406967.aspx) for more info.

Comment: This is what I figured out too.